# Prove derivative of $e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: calculus

How does one use the definition of a derivative to prove that $e^{-1/x^2}$ is derivable in all $x ∈ \mathbb R$.
I have tried to use L'Hôpital's rule but seemingly cannot get it to work. Any help or clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably it is only at $x=0$ that you are having problems? Please let us know how you tried to use l'Hôpital's rule. Otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: Use the chain rule df(g(x))/dx = df/dg dg/dx.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x):=\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$ when $x\ne 0$, and $F(0)=0$. We can prove that this has derivatives of all orders at every point.

**Step 1** Prove by induction on $n$ that for each $n$ there exists a polynomial $p_n$ such that for all $x\ne 0$ we have $F^{(n)}(x)=\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})p_n(\frac{1}{x})$.

This only uses the product rule and the chain rule and is essentially simple algebra.

**Step 2** Prove by induction on $n$ that $F^{(n)}(0)=0$.

This holds for $n=0$ so we need only prove the inductive step. By definition we have that
$$F^{(n+1)}(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F^{(n)}(x)-F^{(n)}(0)}{x-0}$$
if the limit exists.

Substituting $t=\frac{1}{x}$ we see that the limit is
$$\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\exp(-t^2)t p_n(t),$$
which is a finite sum of terms like
$$
\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\frac{t^k}{\exp(t^2)}.$$

Now $\exp(t^2)>\frac{1}{k!}t^{2k}$, so each of these limits is $0$, and so $F^{n+1}(0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer. Though I still do not understand how to prove it for every value of x. I tried using lim h->0 (f(x+h) - f(x))/h and tried using L'Hôpital's rule on the denominator and the numerator but got an expression that is not definable. Is this not the correct approach or have I just made an arithmetic mistake?

Comment: I don't think L'HR is the way to go here. It would be easier to prove from the definition of derivative that the Chain Rule works, that differentiation is linear, and that the Product Rule works. Then all that's not obvious is that the derivative of $\exp$ is $\exp$. At this point all depends on your definition of $\exp$.

Comment: You use $p_n$ and $f_n$ for the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @Gary, I've edited it.