# Showing $e^{-1/x^2}$ is differentiable for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definition

[My attempted solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvWpm.jpg)

I've attempted to use the definition for derivatives $$f'(x) = \dfrac {f(x+h) - f(x)}h$$ as $h$ approaches zero.
I figured that if I can factor out the common term I can use a standard limit value for $(e^h-1)/h$ but it gets pretty clunky and I fail to see a solution. Any input as to what I am missing?

Comment: It is obviously continuous and differentiable for $x \not=0$ by the chain rule and its derivative is $\frac{2}{x^3}e^{-1/x^2}$.  It is also an even function, so all you have to do is show that the limits of $e^{-1/x^2}$ and $\frac{2}{x^3}e^{-1/x^2}$ are $0$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: The same question was asked just four days ago: [Prove derivative of $e^{-1/x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262394/prove-derivative-of-e-1-x2)

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ is differentiable at $x=0$ if it is given that $f(0)=0$.

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/h^2}-0}{h}=\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t}{e^{t^2}}=0,$$
by L-Hospital. So $f'(x)$ is finite at $x=0$ and every where else for $x \in R$.